# Elliot haughin's twitter library redirecting error

Tags: codeigniter, twitter

I'm using Elliot Haughin's twitter library to add twitter login functionality for my codeigniter project [check the library here](https://github.com/vixnet/codeigniter-twitter)

I set the consumer key and secret but when I try to test it; it just stops at 'authenticate' link and doesn't redirect me to anything. I also tried many libraries and I get the same problem.Could you tell me what I did wrong , please ?

edit : I used the console and that's what I get :

```
The value "device-width;" for key "width" is invalid, and has been ignored. authenticate:8
The value "1.0;" for key "initial-scale" was truncated to its numeric prefix. authenticate:8
The value "1.0;" for key "maximum-scale" was truncated to its numeric prefix. authenticate:8
Error parsing a meta element's content: ';' is not a valid key-value pair separator. Please use ',' instead.
```

Comment: Check https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console and check for errors. If there are errors, edit and include in your question.

Comment: I edited the post and added what I get from console

Comment: Oh, sorry - I assumed it was a javascript library. Those are CSS errors which aren't the problem. Check error logs http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html https://www.google.com/search?q=codeigniter+error+logs https://www.google.com/search?q=php+error+log